# How Dapper sets properties without setters

Tags: .net, reflection, orm, dapper, getter-setter

I have a model:

```
    public class Model
    {
        public int Id { get;}

        public string Name { get; }

        public string AnotherName { get; }
    }
```

default constructor, no setters, so that we have no public setter method in a generated class by IL.

BUT `Dapper` somehow initialize my data. All properties are filled.

```
                var sql = $@"SELECT id as Id, name as Name, another_name as AnotherName FROM dapper";

                var raws = (connection.QueryAsync<Model>(sql).Result).AsList();
```

I've found source code and they setting by Setter method, but when I tried to get setter as `Dapper` does, I've got null methodInfo. Here is some `Dapper` source code SqlMapper:3320

```
                    if (specializedConstructor == null)
                    {
                        // Store the value in the property/field
                        if (item.Property != null)
                        {
                            il.Emit(type.IsValueType ? OpCodes.Call : OpCodes.Callvirt, DefaultTypeMap.GetPropertySetter(item.Property, type));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            il.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, item.Field); // stack is now [target]
                        }
                    }
```

and the `DefaultTypeMap.GetPropertySetter`:

```
        internal static MethodInfo GetPropertySetter(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, Type type)
        {
            if (propertyInfo.DeclaringType == type) return propertyInfo.GetSetMethod(true);

            return propertyInfo.DeclaringType.GetProperty(
                   propertyInfo.Name,
                   BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                   Type.DefaultBinder,
                   propertyInfo.PropertyType,
                   propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray(),
                   null).GetSetMethod(true);
        }
```

You can write sample so did I, and you'll see if your property doesn't have any setter, then setter method info will be null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/blob/main/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L3312-L3323
[image: source code]

It stores property in the internal Dapper model, and if the property doesn't have property - it sets it via the backing field.

Comment: "and if the property doesn't have property"? Do you mean "and if the property doesn't have *setter*"?